# MongoDB run locally or through Atlas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

Is it better to learn MongoDB through MongoDB Atlas or to have MongoDB downloaded locally?

When I go to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/getting-started/ I see there are two options for downloading MongoDB. I'm guessing it doesn't matter which one you download but if there is a better option, it would be nice to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're getting started, i suggest the quickest option. Knowing how to configure/install a local instance of Mongo is certainly important, but it can sometimes be a drag and prevent you from the more 'enjoyable' parts of learning a new technology.

I personally recommend going with Atlas at first. After you've seen enough mongo to get familiar with the shell commands, take a swing at installing it locally.